# デビュー作『クビキリサイクル 青色サヴァンと戯言遣い』とは共通項が多いとも述べており、今日子が同作品の舞台となる島に呼ばれてもおかしくない人物であることに触れ、そういう意味でも原点回帰かもしれないと語っている

Tags: meaning, parsing

> 西尾自身は、『暦物語』のころからミステリーを書きたくなってきたと振り返っている[1]。
>   レトリックやダイアローグに凝った作品が多くなってきていたため、本シリーズはその辺りを抑えて書いているという[1]。
>   **デビュー作『クビキリサイクル 青色サヴァンと戯言遣い』とは共通項が多いとも述べており、今日子が同作品の舞台となる島に呼ばれてもおかしくない人物であることに触れ、そういう意味でも原点回帰かもしれないと語っている[1]。**
>
> Nishio Himself reflected that he wanted to write a mistery since the time of Koyomi Monogatari.
>   Since the stories full of rhetoric and dialogs became a lot, with this series he restrained himself on that aspect and started writing.
>   He said that it has many common aspect with his debut work [Neck cutting cycle Blue Savin and the nonsense user] and ....
>   With the debut work [Neck cutting cycle Blue Savin and the nonsense user] it has many common points he said, touching the fact that even if Kyouko were to be called to the island which was the common setting of the novels it would not be a weird character, even that could be a return to  the past he said.

I am really not sure at all I understand this sentence.

How should I parse the bold sentence?

Comment: 西尾さんは、「①(本シリーズは、)デビュー作『クビキリサイクル 青色サヴァンと戯言遣い』とは共通項が多い。」とも言っていて、「②今日子は**同作品** (= デビュー作『クビキリサイクル 青色サヴァンと戯言遣い』) の舞台となる島に呼ばれてもおかしくない人物だ。」と言いながら、「③そういう意味でも原点回帰かもしれない。」と言いました。(あと、「～さ‌​れてもおかしくない」を辞書で調べたほうがいいかもしれません。）

Comment: さ‌​れてもおかしくない=Even if something were being done it would not be weird, Am I right?

Comment: 逐語訳するとそうなるかもしれませんが、普通は「～してもおかしくない」は「～しそうだ」や「～して当然だ」などの意味で使います。is likely to~~ や might well do~~ などになるかと思います。(ここでは Kyoko is the kind of character who you might expect to be~~ とかいう感じでしょうか？) [ここ](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) や[ここ](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%22%E3%82%82%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%22) が参考になるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would parse as follows:

> He said that this series has many common aspect with his debut work *Neck cutting cycle Blue Savin and the nonsense user*, pointing out that if Kyouko were to be called to the island -which was the common setting of the novels- she would fit fine in the setting. In that sense, this series is like going back to his origin [as a writer].

Since you got most of it right, I was hoping I could just leave a comment, but I don't think my reputation allows me to comment.